# sql server convert string to datetime

Tags: sql, string, datetime

I have this string: '30/05/2010', and I would like to enter it to a smallDatetime field.
In the database it should look something like this 2010-05-30 15:33:25
Any Idea how?

TY

Comment: Any chance you can convert it client-side first? Typically most programming languages and runtimes have far better ways to do this than the database engine.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
select convert(smalldatetime,'30/05/2010',103)
```

Comment: This page lists all of the date/time formats supported by the convert function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY 
SELECT CAST('30/05/2010' as smalldatetime)
```

Where do you want the time aspect to come from? The convert above will append 00:00 (midnight) for smalldatetime because:

- the string has no time information
- smalldatetime resolves to a minute resolution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `datetime` field type if you want in this format `2010-05-30 15:33:25`. If you want only the date, use the `date` type only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cast('05/30/2010' as smalldatetime)`.

If you need to have exact `15:33:25` time then you can use several [dateadd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) calls, e.g. `select dateadd(hh, 15, cast('05/30/2010' as smalldatetime))` returns `2010-05-30 15:00:00`.

Comment: But my string is 30/05/2010 and not 05/30/2010. cast didn't work on my string.

Comment: Thats because of different culture settings.